# d3.json method doesn't return my data array

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise

I'm using `d3.json` to load a JSON file containing my data, like this:

```
var data = d3.json(url, callback)
```

If I do a `console.log(data)` I can see that `data` is neither empty nor `null`. However, it doesn't seem to contain my data array, but something else instead.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

<sup>Note: this is a self-answered question, [trying to provide a "canonical" Q&A on a subject that has been touched on by many previous questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314272/5768908) and not (clearly) explained by the API. The answer below was written as a general guidance to those questions.</sup>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### TL;DR

`d3.json` (as well as `d3.csv`, `d3.tsv` etc) does not return the content of the loaded/parsed file. Instead of that, it returns an object related to the request in D3 v4 or lower, and a promise in D3 v5 or higher.

#### What does d3.json return? (v4 or lower)

`d3.json` is one of the alternatives to `XMLHttpRequest` provided by D3. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json), `d3.json`...

> Returns a new request to get the JSON file at the specified url with the default mime type application/json.

... which, we can agree, is not particularly clear. Because of that, you probably thought that you could return the *loaded data* using `var data = d3.json(url, callback)`, but that's incorrect. What `d3.json` returns is an *object* (not an array), associated with the request. Let's see it.

I have this JSON in a file:

```
{"foo": "42"}
```

What happens if we use `d3.json` the way you used it in your question? Click "run code snippet" to see:

```js
var data = d3.json("https://api.npoint.io/5b22a0474c99d3049d2e", function() {});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see in the console, we have an object like this:

```
{header: ƒ, mimeType: ƒ, responseType: ƒ, timeout: ƒ, user: ƒ, …}
```

Well, this is not our data array.

The same thing happens if you use a function:

```js
function getData() {
  return d3.json("https://api.npoint.io/5b22a0474c99d3049d2e", function() {})
}

var data = getData()

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that the same thing happens with `d3.csv`, `d3.tsv` and the other request methods:

```js
var data = d3.csv("https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SVU13_7.2.1/com.ibm.ismsaas.doc/reference/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv", function() {});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

#### How to use d3.json?

The correct way to load the data with `d3.json`, as you can see in several online examples, is using its callback:

```
d3.json(url, function(data){
    //use data here...
});
```

And here is the snippet with our JSON file:

```js
d3.json("https://api.npoint.io/5b22a0474c99d3049d2e", function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

You can also call another function: the data will be passed as the first argument. Here is a demo:

```js
d3.json("https://api.npoint.io/5b22a0474c99d3049d2e", callback)

function callback(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

#### What does d3.json return? (v5 or higher)

In D3 v5, `d3.json` (as well as `d3.csv`, `d3.tsv` etc) returns a promise:

```js
var data = d3.json("https://api.npoint.io/5b22a0474c99d3049d2e");

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Check it in your browser's console, not the Stack snippet console.