# Parse csv as object with extra property

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to load a csv data file into a d3 tree graph. I can get the json data version working but d3.csv parser doesn't return the same string.

I have tried:

```
treeData.forEach(function (d) {
```

and:

```
data.map(function(d) { return [ d[" "],
```

but these reference specific header strings

I need to wrap the d3.csv result with:

```
{name: "root", children: []}
```

but not using jsontostring

Below shows what I have been using and the results in chrome console:

```
treeJSON = d3.json("test.json", function(error, treeDataJSON) { console.log(treeDataJSON); });
```

> result:    {name: "root", children: Array(6)}
>       children: Array(6)
>       0: {name: "A", values: "v1", more values: "v7"}
>       1: {name: "B", values: "v2", more values: "v8"}
>       2: {name: "C", values: "v3", more values: "v9"}
>       3: {name: "D", values: "v4", more values: "v10"}
>       4: {name: "E", values: "v5", more values: "v11"}
>       5: {name: "F", values: "v6", more values: "v12"}

```
treeCSV = d3.csv("test.csv", function(error, treeDataCSV) { console.log(treeDataCSV); });
```

> result:
>       (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>       0: {name: "A", values: "v1", more values: "v7"}
>       1: {name: "B", values: "v2", more values: "v8"}
>       2: {name: "C", values: "v3", more values: "v9"}
>       3: {name: "D", values: "v4", more values: "v10"}
>       4: {name: "E", values: "v5", more values: "v11"}
>       5: {name: "F", values: "v6", more values: "v12"}

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite straightforward: inside the callback, just declare a literal object and use the parsed data (that you named `treeDataCSV`) for setting the `children` value:

```
const treeData = {
    name: "root",
    children: treeDataCSV
};
```

Here is a simple demo, using `d3.csvParse` instead of `d3.csv`, but the solution is exactly the same:

```js
const csv = `name,values,more values
A,v1,v7
B,v2,v8
C,v3,v9
D,v4,v10
E,v5,v11
F,v6,v12`;

const treeDataCSV = d3.csvParse(csv);

const treeData = {
  name: "root",
  children: treeDataCSV
};

console.log(treeData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

It's also worth mentioning that, given your `d3.csv` signature, you're using D3 V4 or below. That being the case, you cannot do `treeCSV = d3.csv(etc...`, as you are doing. For an explanation please have a look here: [d3.json doesn't return my data array in D3 v4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47664292/5768908)